# Strange deletion warning trying to clean up old questions (that aren't mine)

Tags: bug, status-review, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete, warning-message

Occasionally I encounter old questions that got popular, but which are actually pretty bad. One common case is that the question Needs More Focus due to really being two questions in one, each of which has a better, properly focused canonical. (For example, it might have been a debugging question where there were two unrelated problems with the code.). I'll hammer it with both duplicates, downvote as I see fit, and then try to cast a delete vote - whereupon I am told the question cannot be deleted as there are other questions closed as a duplicate of it.

Fair enough. All of those questions should have been linked to one of the other canonicals anyway; so I'll go through the linked questions and re-link them as appropriate. Then I go back and try to cast a delete vote again (with more conviction this time, since I specifically want to prevent it from being used as a target again when there are clearly better targets available).

When I do so, generally I am presented with this warning:

[image: deletion warning]

I don't understand why. I am pretty sure that this warning is intended for when deleting one's own questions, not when voting to delete someone else's.

Comment: When did you start seeing this warning - since forever, or only recently? I vote to delete questions often enough and have never seen this.

Comment: I can recall having seen it months ago, but not in enough detail to discuss. Triggering this warning might or might not require the first attempt to cast a delete vote, and might have something to do with if/when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I got this yesterday when I attempted to vote to delete a question which had a duplicate. After I changed the duplicate to point to a different question, I got this warning a couple of times, but by the time I tried to get a screen shot, I could no longer repro. Before yesterday, I had never seen this.